# Why does UNION return less rows than one of its subrequests with MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, union

`UNION` can be used to merge the rows of two sub-requests:

```
SELECT column_name FROM table1
UNION
SELECT column_name FROM table2;
```

By default, MySQL's `UNION` is actually `UNION DISTINCT`, which means that the rows `table1` and `table2` have in common are de-duplicated. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1;

--------
| name |
--------
| John |
| Mary |
--------

SELECT * FROM table_2;

---------
| name  |
---------
| John  |
| Steve |
---------

SELECT * FROM table1
UNION
SELECT * FROM table2;

---------
| name  |
---------
| John  |
| Mary  |
| Steve |
---------
```

Note that `John` is present only once in the final result, because MySQL de-duplicate this row.

We can say that `UnionRows.length <= Table1Rows.length + Table2Rows.length`.

However, I'm facing an unexpected behavior. I have `UnionRows.length < Table1Rows.length`. Which means that when I merge two sets, I get less rows than just taking one of the set. I would expect to have `UnionRows.length >= Table1Rows.length` and `UnionRows.length >= Table2Rows.length`.

Comment: Why should that behaviour be unexpected?

Comment: And you can even do `select * from t union select * from t` to emulate `select distinct * from t`. SQL is such fun!

Comment: @JonasMetzler Well, I'm not used to SQL's UNION. Plus my two sub-requests don't overlap so I was definitely expecting a strict merge here. Just to clarify, I found out myself and posted both the question and the answer on SO because I couldn't find this information anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `UNION` also de-duplicates rows *in each sub-request*. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1;

--------
| name |
--------
| John |
| John |
| John |
--------

SELECT * FROM table_2;

---------
| name  |
---------
| Steve |
---------

SELECT * FROM table1
UNION
SELECT * FROM table2;

---------
| name  |
---------
| John  |
| Steve |
---------
```

Note that the final result has less rows than `table_1`.

Answer (score 2):

By default ISO standard SQL of UNION operator induce the DISTINCT of the resulting subset, not a DISTINCT over each query that compound the all statement.

This allow all combination of DISTINCT at every level.

Demo...

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (name1 VARCHAR(16));
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('Fred'), ('Fred'), ('Dave');
CREATE TABLE T2 (name2 VARCHAR(16));
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES ('Dave'), ('John'), ('Dave');

-- no duplicate at all
SELECT * FROM T1
UNION 
SELECT * FROM T2

name1
----------------
Dave
Fred
John

-- duplicate only for T1
SELECT ALL * FROM T1
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM T2

name1
----------------
Fred
Fred
Dave
Dave
John


-- duplicate only for T2
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM T1
UNION ALL
SELECT ALL * FROM T2

name1
----------------
Dave
Fred
Dave
John
Dave

-- duplicate for all
SELECT ALL * FROM T1
UNION ALL
SELECT ALL * FROM T2

name1
----------------
Fred
Fred
Dave
Dave
John
Dave
```

Remember that ALL is by default in SELECT, by DISTINCT is by default in set based operators like UNION, DISTINCT, EXCEPT...